# Publishing a Headless ecommerce. Which Costs i need to consider?

Tags: webserver, publish, headless, netlify, vercel

I'm developing an **ecommerce website**.

It's for a "ground-based" clothing store that is used to sells only via third party platform.

 And now want a own website.

**I started with Wordpress+Woocommerce.**

**Then i tried a ZeitNow+Next+Graphql+React** version.

It connects itself to Wordpress+Woocomerce database via GraphQL Queries.
It uses ZeitNow to avoid implementing a real Node+Express server on my machine.

## Which path to choose to complete the website and publish it ? 
My doubts are related mainly to **COSTS**.

---

**If i choose the classic WP+Woocommerce** way i need :

0-20 EUR /year for Domain Name.

120EUR / year approximately for a classic web server (with PHP+MySQL) hosting plan where to place the Wordpress+Woocommerce.

---

**If i'd like to choose second option**, based on what i know actually i need :

0-20 EUR /year for Domain Name.

120EUR / year approximately for a classic web server (with PHP+MySQL) hosting plan where to place the Wordpress+Woocommerce "head" part of my project, .

0EUR /year for serveless ZeitNow (free plan).

---

But **where i need to place the "App**" (ZeitNow+Next+GraphQl+React)?

An other Web server (with Node) ?

So an other 120EUR/ year plan ?

Or beacuse it's serverless i can only "deploy" to zeitNow and only link my domain to ZeitNow?

Its not clear to me.

I found on the web things like "Netifly", "Firebase", "Heroku", "AWS" ... 

 Are they all equivalent to Zeit Now?

---

**I would like to publish a website with benefits of WooCommerce CMS system.**

Like adding products, managing stocks, handling discounts plans, access to PayPal and Stripe payment methods integrations (i don't trust my self enough to build integration on my own due to security risks).

**I wolud like also the keep benefits of using React for front End** like performance (at least perceived) for Final User, or no need of Ajax request to update Cart and Wishlist.

And **what about calculating if my project needs a "payed plan" of ZeitNow/Netifly/AWS** to manage the request? How i can calculate them?

Sorry for the high number of question, but for me, understand the co-existence of these things is overwhelming!

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot run an e-commerce on the "Free" plan of ZEIT Now. if we detect this usage we will issue a warning and, if it is ignored, the site will be shut down. Check https://zeit.co/legal/terms for more information

Answer (score 0):

1. You will always need a paid plan on any platform if you are running a for-profit endeavor.
2. You may need ZEIT Now to host your frontend and another server for the GraphQL API unless you really want to go DevOps-less by using serverless functions.
3. Here are very relevant pages for calculating costs:

   1. [ZEIT Now pricing page](https://zeit.co/pricing). Notice the "Serverless Execution" and also "BandWidth" prices.
   2. [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/pricing/).
   3. [AWS](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html).

In the end, you will need to deploy a "Proof-of-Concept" and be really careful with the metrics. It is impossible to pinpoint an exact number with a custom solution because depending on your implementation, it can be more or less expensive to make API calls. Solutions like Shopify may be the best approach for your type of app. I only recommend that you develop your own stack if you want to customize, scale, and prepare the base for a team of developers later.

*Disclaimer: I work for ZEIT at the moment.*

Comment: If want to use WP+Woocommerce as CMS and i build a Node+Express server inside my app , i need two "real" servers ..Right?   It is possible to have only one server that let me use PHP and Node togheter, maybe wth some "partition" ( like an Had Disk) and "routing" ? I dont like to have two servers, so im looking for something that can let me use WP and React togheter, im checking "Frontify" that i discovered today , but maybe it's not ideal for Woocommerce.I prefere to not use Shopify cause it's expensive and it's not customizable as Wordpress is.